# How to enable X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I need to send files created by `tmpfile()` on the serverside to the browser.

I am using two difeerent Docker containers: `php` and `nginx` (docker compose).

My nginx conf (Docker container `nginx`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
 
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
 
    root /app;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size on;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
 
    error_log  stderr warn;
    access_log  /dev/stdout main;
}
```

My PHP code (Docker container `php`):

```php
<?php

$file = tmpfile();
fwrite($file, "hello world");

$metaData = stream_get_meta_data($file);
$fileName = $metaData['uri'];

header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $fileName);

fclose($file);
```

But the browser only gets an empty page istead of a download popup.

Comment: You can't do it using the `tmpfile()`. Do you need a detailed answer why and what can be suggested instead?

Comment: @IvanShatsky Why ist tmpfile() not possible? And what would be an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, lets start from the beginning.

1. It should be obvious that the nginx will need a direct access to the file that will be served via `X-Accel-Redirect` header. That means that you will need some kind of a shared volume between your `nginx` and `php` containers. Usually it isn't a problem (see the [How To Share Data between Docker Containers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers) article for example). But `tmpfile()` will create a temporary file in a temporary directory (`/tmp` or something like that) and making it a shared volume between the containers can be quite tricky.
2. Even if you'd manage to solve the previous part, after the `fclose($file);` line the temporary file will be closed and deleted. That's the main part why trying to use `tmpfile()` and `X-Accel-Redirect` together is a bad idea. Well, you can try to flash the output buffers and wait a couple of time to give nginx a chance to read the file before your script closes and deletes the file, but I'm not sure it will work at all and it doesn't seems to be a good solution either.

What can you do instead?

First of all, you don't need to stuck with the `X-Accel-Redirect` at all. It can give you significant performance benefit when you want to serve the already existed file using nginx. But you are about to create that file first, writing a couple of data to disk with PHP and reading it from disk with the nginx. You can simply write that data directly to the `STDOUT`.

The disadvantage of that approach is that you don't know an amount of your data beforehand and can't set the proper `Content-Length` header making your data served via chunked-encoded HTTP stream. If you don't want to do it that way, you can use the output buffering `ob_...` functions. Start buffering with the [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), then after all your data has been written to the buffer use [`ob_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) to get its contents and [`ob_get_length()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php) to get the data size and then close output buffer with the [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php). Now you will be able to properly set the `Content-Length` header before sending the data to the `STDOUT` (or return a proper error code if something goes wrong).

As a last resort, if you are still want to use exactly the `tmpfile()` one, you can output its contents to the `STDOUT` before closing/deleting it using the [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function.